# Product of orthogonal projections need not be a projection

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A,B be square matrices with real entries. If A and B are orthogonal projections, then AB is projection. True or false?

My proof: projection requires $X^2 = X$, so $(AB)^2 = A^2 B^2 = AB \Rightarrow $ AB is projection.

But the answer should be 'the statement is false'. What did I miss?

Answer (score 2):

You assumed that $AB = BA$, but that's not true at all: the result of applying $A$ second will put any input vector into the subspace associated with $A$'s image, while applying $B$'s image will put the input vector into the subspace associated with $B$'s image.  As long as those image subspaces are different, these projections should not commute.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof almost has a counter example built in. Notice that $(AB)^2 = ABAB$ and it's not always true that $ABAB = A^2B^2$. Find an example of projections $A$ and $B$ such that $AB \neq BA$ and you should be on your way to finding a counter example!