# Product of orthogonal projections

Tags: linear-algebra

I need an example of two **orthogonal projections** such that their product is not a **projection**.

I'm aware of this: [Product of orthogonal projections need not be a projection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823978/product-of-orthogonal-projections-need-not-be-a-projection)
Unfortunately, I've no idea of how to construct such matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try any two such projections, and you'll *probably* come up with an example.

**Example:**
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad B = \frac 12 \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}
$$
We have
$$
AB = \frac 12 \pmatrix{1&1\\0&0}\\
(AB)^2 = \frac 14 \pmatrix{1&1\\0&0}
$$